# Multiple linear regression - assumption of normaly distributed estimates

Tags: multiple-regression, normality-assumption, dependent-variable, back-transformation

In linear regression, there is said that normal distribution of residuals is required. Other than that I have found that it can be violated if the dataset is large enough. But what is large enough? Is there a certain number?

I am asking this because I need to model multiple linear regression to estimate effect of physical activity metric on fat mass indicator. I use covariates as sex, age and others ...  But the problem is that the residuals are not normally distributed. I have tested it with qqplot and ks.test.

As an option, I have used natural logarithm or square root for transforming the dependent variable which helps, but as now, I have problems with interpreting the results.

I have been told that to back transform the logged estimate I should use exponential function. In case of squared estimate I should square it back. But how do I interpret it, because my *Beta* coefficient is negative (eg. -0,266) as it confirms that more physical activity -> less fat mass. But when I use exp or square it gives me always positive results... Which is somewhat counterintuitive.

Could you please help me with this problem?

---

Edit and actualization:
As reply to comments below I have changed the aproache a little bit:
There are plot's of:
Linearity of the data.
Normality of residuals.
Homogeneity of residuals variance.
Independence of residuals error terms.

[image]

The density plot for residuals is as follows:

[image]

The $p$-value of ks.test for residuals is lower than 0.05

If I log transform the dependent variable then visualisation seems better and ks.test $p$-value is $> 0.05$.

My dependent variable is Fat mass index. I do have 338 obesrvations.

I have done the linar regression model for other dependent variables such as BMI *z*-score, fat mass percent and visceral fat mass area. All these models are all right with the required assumptions so I feel all right to interpret it.

However this last model with fat mass index is making me afraid because I wouldn't like to use different approche. But if it would be necessary to use different modelling, what would it be? GLM for gamma distribution?

Thank you for answers!

Excuse my possible mistakes. I am relatively new to statistics...

Comment: As a heads up, it does not matter if the pooled distribution of your dependent variable (the “y” column in your data frame) is normal. It matters if the error term is normal, and this is inferred from the residuals, not from the data themselves.

Comment: There is no requirement for the raw dependent variable to be normally distributed. Where have you read that ? For certain inferential purposes it might be helpful for the residuals to follow, approximately, a normal distribution.

Comment: @Dave thank you for clarification. It was my misunderstanding. 
I have checked for the normality of residuals and they don't fit the normal distribution. According to this article (https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jclinepi.2017.12.006) it shouldn't be problem if I have more than 10 observations and I do have 320. Is it possible? 
What are other things that I could do? Thank you a lot! I am really new to these things...

Comment: @RobertLong thank you for answer. In the past weeks I have read a lot about it so it might be my misinterpretation I am sorry for that. Anyway I have checked for the residuals and they are not normally distributed either. What do you mean by approximately is there any cut point? In the comment above I postet link that says it is possible to ignore the violation from normality if there is enough observations is it possible? Thank you for helping. I am just starting to learn this...

Comment: No real-world data follows a normal distribution *exactly*. Please edit your post to show us how you determined that they are not approximately normal.

Comment: The qqplot indicates a right-skeed distribution of residuals. What is your response variable? Weight? BMI? ... tell us! Maybe show us a plot, and other contextual info, number of observations, what is the covariables, ... Maybe you could try a gm, maybe a gamma glm?